# How to disable "Run execution to here" in Visual Studio 15?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do I disable "Run execution to here" button that appears when moving cursor to the left of the code? It's really annoying when I accidentally click it while selecting code.

[image]

Comment: Never found this feature useful, only gave me headaches when accidentally pushing it

Comment: Agreed - not a helpful feature, just an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Seems like a serious UX oversight. "Hey guys, let's make a button appear underneath someone's mouse. What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: Tyty! This is a terrible feature btw.

Comment: This is the single most annoying feature I've seen since upgrading from VS2013... Constantly screws me over selecting variables while debugging / analyzing bugs...

Comment: I would say this is horror feature - especially when you debug something for 30 minutes and accidentally click on it while selecting text. This should be moved to line number only.

Comment: The position and / or the "timing" of the button are the problem for me. The feature itsseft might be a good idea.

Comment: actually I have found this feature by mistake, i.e I clicked it by mistake and realized that it is quite useful. I've already started using it. But I guess it is useful to know how to turn it off

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Uncheck **Show run to click button in editor while debugging** at the very end of Debugging options:

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio -> Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> 
Uncheck the check box "Show Run to Click button while debugging".

For those who can't access the above image

Answer (score 27):

[image]

A slight difference in Visual Studio 2019